How to have websites in safari always ask to download?
How to have websites in safari always ask for permission to download?
I have set GitHub.com, to ask to download.

I get the download prompt, when I try to download a GitHub Repo zip.
After downloading, where it previously said "ask" for GitHub.com, now it says "Allow".
How can I have it always be set on ask?
Thank you!
Additional information:
Safari Version 18.0 (20619.1.26.31.6)
macOS 15.0 (24A335)
